# How to arrange fields in a vb.net report

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer, report

I am using VS2010. I am trying to make reports using Report Viewer. This is how I have arranged my fields (using Table).

[image]

I want to make it look like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a list for this, which is like a repeater control in ASP.net if you are familiar:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159121.aspx

Comment: It says, "Drag fields from the Report Data pane to the cell" but where is the report data pane ?

Comment: Ah I got it I had to go to View and select Report Data.

Comment: Have you tried setting the "repeat with" property for the controls you're dropping in the list control?